# One Calendar for Multiple Email Accounts in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, calendar

I'm trying to have one calendar for two of my accounts in Outlook 2016 (an Exchange account and a Gmail account).  Is there a way to have one calendar for the both of them?  I'm sick of double checking.  And no, having the two of them side-by-side won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can display two calendars at once.  I am not sure I understand your question.  Unless you have already grandfathered the Google account, you can't sync your Google Calendar, to Outlook (Google discontinued that years ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is feasible to use one calendar for two accounts in Outlook. For your scenario, I'd like to suggest [subscribing to the Google Calendar in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126), then use Overlay view so that the two calendars can be visually merged into one:

[overlay view of two calendars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwIm1.png)